# How to import window class from other file

Tags: python, pyqt6

I start writing program with PyQt6. I created few windows classes in one file, It's works fine but my code is little mess. I want to throw any class to other file, can you tell me how to do it best?

Here is my one file code

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QFrame, QMainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Menu ')
        self.init_ui()
        self.setFixedSize(800, 600)
        #utwórz obiekt ramki
        frame = QFrame(self)
        frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.Shape.VLine)
        frame.setLineWidth(2)
        frame.setGeometry(120, 10, 1, 600) # Pozycja(Horizontal, vertical), Wielkość ramki(Szerokość, Wysokość )

    def init_ui(self):
        label = QLabel('To jest menu ', self)
        label.move(150, 50)

        button_menu = QPushButton('Main Menu', self)
        button_menu.move(10, 10)
        button_menu.clicked.connect(self.show_menu)

        button_sale = QPushButton('Sprzedaz', self)
        button_sale.move(10, 40)
        button_sale.clicked.connect(self.show_sale)

        button_costs = QPushButton('Koszty', self)
        button_costs.move(10, 70)
        button_costs.clicked.connect(self.show_costs)

    def show_menu(self):
        self.hide
        window_menu.show()

    def show_sale(self):
        self.hide()
        window_sale.show()

    def show_costs(self):
        self.hide()





class SaleWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Sale')
        self.init_ui()
        self.setFixedSize(800, 600)
        # utwórz obiekt ramki
        frame = QFrame(self)
        frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.Shape.VLine)
        frame.setLineWidth(2)
        frame.setGeometry(70, 5, 100, 200) # Pozycja(Horizontal, vertical), Wielkość ramki(Szerokość, Wysokość )

    def init_ui(self):
        label = QLabel('To jest sprzedaz ', self)
        label.move(150, 50)

        button_menu = QPushButton('Main Menu', self)
        button_menu.move(10, 10)
        button_menu.clicked.connect(self.show_menu)

        button_sale = QPushButton('Sprzedaz', self)
        button_sale.move(10, 40)
        button_sale.clicked.connect(self.show_sale)

        button_costs = QPushButton('Koszty', self)
        button_costs.move(10, 70)
        button_costs.clicked.connect(self.show_costs)

        button_invoice = QPushButton('Faktury', self)
        button_invoice.move(10, 100)
        button_invoice.clicked.connect(self.invoice)

    def show_menu(self):
        self.hide
        window_menu.show()

    def show_sale(self):
        self.hide()
        window_sale.show()

    def show_costs(self):
        self.hide()
        window_cost.show()

    def invoice(self):
        self.hide()
        window_inv.show()
   


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window_menu = MainWindow()
    window_sale = SaleWindow()
    window_cost = CostsWindow()
    window_inv = InvWin()
    win_add_inv = add_invoice()

    window_menu.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I try to push `SaleWindows` class to sale_window.py like that:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QFrame, QMainWindow
from KPiR_windows import *

class SaleWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Sale')
        self.init_ui()
        self.setFixedSize(800, 600)
        # utwórz obiekt ramki
        frame = QFrame(self)
        frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.Shape.VLine)
        frame.setLineWidth(2)
        frame.setGeometry(70, 5, 100, 200) # Pozycja(Horizontal, vertical), Wielkość ramki(Szerokość, Wysokość )

    def init_ui(self):
        label = QLabel('To jest sprzedaz ', self)
        label.move(150, 50)

        button_menu = QPushButton('Main Menu', self)
        button_menu.move(10, 10)
        button_menu.clicked.connect(self.show_menu)

        button_sale = QPushButton('Sprzedaz', self)
        button_sale.move(10, 40)
        button_sale.clicked.connect(self.show_sale)

        button_costs = QPushButton('Koszty', self)
        button_costs.move(10, 70)
        button_costs.clicked.connect(self.show_costs)

        button_invoice = QPushButton('Faktury', self)
        button_invoice.move(10, 100)
        button_invoice.clicked.connect(self.invoice)

    def show_menu(self):
        self.hide
        window_menu.show()

    def show_sale(self):
        self.hide()
        window_sale.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window_menu = MainWindow()
    window_sale = SaleWindow()
    window_cost = CostsWindow()
    window_inv = InvWin()
    win_add_inv = add_invoice()

    window_menu.show()
```

And import it to main file, but I got problem with circular import. Can you help me and tell me how to do it better? Or maybe my thinking is wrong? Maybe it have to be in one file or in one 'Main' class?

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
cannot import name 'SaleWindow' from partially initialized module 'sale_window' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/konrad/Desktop/Projekty/KPIR/sale_window.py)
  File "/Users/konrad/Desktop/Projekty/KPIR/KPiR_windows.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sale_window import SaleWindow
  File "/Users/konrad/Desktop/Projekty/KPIR/sale_window.py", line 3, in <module>
    from KPiR_windows import *
  File "/Users/konrad/Desktop/Projekty/KPIR/KPiR_windows.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sale_window import SaleWindow
```

@Edit:

My main file now looks like below:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QFrame, QMainWindow
from sale_window import SaleWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Menu ')
        self.init_ui()
        self.setFixedSize(800, 600)
        #utwórz obiekt ramki
        frame = QFrame(self)
        frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.Shape.VLine)
        frame.setLineWidth(2)
        frame.setGeometry(120, 10, 1, 600) # Pozycja(Horizontal, vertical), Wielkość ramki(Szerokość, Wysokość )

    def init_ui(self):
        label = QLabel('To jest menu ', self)
        label.move(150, 50)

        button_menu = QPushButton('Main Menu', self)
        button_menu.move(10, 10)
        button_menu.clicked.connect(self.show_menu)

        button_sale = QPushButton('Sprzedaz', self)
        button_sale.move(10, 40)
        button_sale.clicked.connect(self.show_sale)

        button_costs = QPushButton('Koszty', self)
        button_costs.move(10, 70)
        button_costs.clicked.connect(self.show_costs)

    def show_menu(self):
        self.hide
        window_menu.show()

    def show_sale(self):
        self.hide()
        window_sale.show()

    def show_costs(self):
        self.hide()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window_menu = MainWindow()
    window_sale = SaleWindow()


    window_menu.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Well, you have `SaleWindow` class in both snippets/class...

Comment: Declaration SaleWindow class is only in sale_window.py

Comment: And how does `KPiR_windows.py` looks like, because the circular import is between `sale_window.py` and `KPiR_windows.py`? Why do you import `SaleWindow` in `KPiR_windows`? Maybe you should move it there

Comment: I want to move all Windows classes to other files because it looks very messy in one file. But I'm not sure now, it is good practice?

Comment: There's nothing wrong about moving classes in other files to keep code more clean. The problem is that wildcard imports should always be avoided unless you really know what you're doing. As written above, you probably did something wrong in `KPiR_windows.py` which causes a circular import, so either you fix that aspect or you do *not* use wildcard imports. But we cannot tell you anything more if we don't know what's in that file.